# Html form using SMTP Server by use of JAVA?

Tags: java, html

I have a general contact form. I want the user to be able to enter in their email in a field, enter their message and it send to the clients email. Is it possible to incorporate JAVA code in a html file to login to their SMTP and send the mail. I do not know PHP is not an option. Is this possible? I know you cant with Javascript which  is a shame.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an [HttpServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) that uses the [JavaMail API](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) to wrap and send the form fields in an e-mail.

I strongly advise agains using JavaScript for direct SMTP, as this would mean

1. to make your user download the mail client implementation (as js) when she wants to contact you
2. that you give away your SMTP authentication data in said JavaScript, effectively opening up sour mail server to anybody else.